# extend type return never in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, extends

I was trying to create IwentyFourHourTimes type and entends the TwelveHourTimes type to it with some additional string (check below code) however the TwentyFourHourTimes return type never instead of TwelveHourTimes and some additional strings

```
export type TwelveHourTimes =
| "01"
| "02"
| "03"
| "04"
| "05"
| "06"
| "07"
| "08"
| "09"
| "10"
| "12";

export type TwentyFourHourTimes =
TwelveHourTimes & ("13"
| "14"
| "15"
| "16"
| "17"
| "18"
| "19"
| "20"
| "21"
| "22"
| "23"
| "00");
```

Comment: `&` is *intersection*. The intersection between `1 | 2 | 3` and `3 | 4 | 5` is `3`. The intersection between two types that have no overlap is `never`. You just want `|` to sum the two unions.

Comment: oh, do you mean something like this: type TwentyFourHourTimes = TwelveHourTimes | '13' | '14'

Comment: Literally replace `&` with `|`